# Infix to Postfix/Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: postfix-notation, infix-notation, polish-notation

If I wanted to convert this from infix to postfix:

```
3 + ( 8 – ( ( 6 – 2 ) ) ) / ( 4 + 5 )
```

Would this be correct?:

```
3 8 6 2 - - + 4 5 + /
```

Also, if I wanted to evaluate this:

```
3 8 6 2 - - 4 5 + / +
```

Would it simplify to this?:

```
31/9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `3 + ( 8 – ( ( 6 – 2 ) ) ) / ( 4 + 5 )` would return `A B C D - - E F + / +` and

yes this:`3 8 6 2 - - 4 5 + / +` simplifies to `31 / 9`